# Array bound of exception in Split Text Processor

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am using nifi 1.1.1 package. I applied the patch files in the source code by referring the below link due to issue faced **"Destination cannot be within sources"** while split flowfile when make header count greater than 0. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3255. 
After apply patches, split text processor works fine, if the header line count given as 0 and above 1.
Those changes in Split text processor can works if we have lesser number of rows only. **For example:** if flowfile contains 1000 rows it could be split.
If the input file contains more than 20000 rows then it doesn't splits the data and leads `"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" exception.
Here i attached image in which faced. 
Anyone please guide me way to resolve that issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNKI0.png

Answer (score 0):

After some digging it seems that you have run into a problem in the 1.1 version of Nifi.

As discussed [here](http://apache-nifi.1125220.n5.nabble.com/SplitText-is-throwing-ArrayIndexOutofBoundException-td16288.html), upgrading to Nifi 1.2 or above should resolve the issue.